# How to calculate the hill area in Google Earth

Tags: area

I want to calculate the area of this hill (the 3D area not flat area) located in Google Maps.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Oujda,+Morocco/@34.4788585,-2.0182252,434m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0xd7864984106d6ef:0x1d86b33244c4650!8m2!3d34.681962!4d-1.900155

Here its photo :

[image]

Comment: Have a look at this [tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/surface-volume.htm) in ArcPro, will give you an idea of what you need to answer your question.